# jQuery ajaxSetup() with validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to use the dataFilter to remove '//' from the beginning of json strings returned from the validate plugin and I'm having some issues getting it to work.  The relevant portions of my code are:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function(data, type){
    return type == 'json' ? data.replace(/^(\/{2})?/, '') : data;
    }
});
    $("#myForm").validate({ 
        rules: {
            cgroup :{
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: compath + "/v.cfc?method=queryRemote&returnformat=json",
                    type: "post"
                }
            }
```

Other rules and messages have been truncated out.

Since switching to Coldfusion 10, which now prepends JSON with a security string (//) as the first two characters I need to fix this on the response side.

I'm not sure if my error is in the ajaxSetup or the use of that with validate() or the regex itself.

There are now errors in the console.  In looking at the response data in Fiddler I see the expected //true or //false if I access the CFC on the newer server, and true or false if I post to the CFC on the server that does not pre-pend the // characters.

However I see no indication that $.ajaxSetup() is doing anything at all.

ANSWER:  jquery.validate() breaks ajaxSetup().  The solution is to move the datafilter down into the remote section:

```
cgroup :{
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: compath + "/v.cfc?method=queryRemote&returnformat=json",
                    type: "post",
                    dataFilter: function(data, type){
                     return type == 'json' ? data.replace(/^(\/{2})?/, '') : data;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the error being displayed in the console?

Comment: Yes, mentioning any errors in your OP would be a pretty good idea.  If you don't know what's causing the error, how would we when we can't even see it?

Comment: There are no errors in the console.  If I look at the response sent back from the server it's //true or //false.  If my cfc to post the data to is http:// it seems to work OK.  If I go back to https:// it stops validating and I don't show any response (but on the old server that doesn't add the // to the JSON response it see the correct true or false response.

Comment: It's not being caused by `.validate()`.  It simply needs to see a `true` or `false` coming back from server.

Comment: Thanks Sparky - my problem is that it's returning //true or //false which causes the validate to fail. I'm trying to get those // stripped from the response so that the validate plugin just gets true/false back.

Comment: Then strip them out at the source function... not at the destination with JS.

Comment: Not possible.  CF10 added that security token to all JSON responses.  After much research and reading it seems that jquery.validate() breaks ajaxSetup().